# OBSOLETE - StackX - Android application for Stack Exchange (Free) (UI and optimization upgrade)

Tags: app, obsolete, android

**Update: 4/15/2013: Screenshots updated according to latest layout**

An android application that will allow the user to browse through all of stack exchange websites using API v2.1.

1. Browse any of the Stack Exchange websites with ability to write
   comment. (NO write for answer or question).
2. Login and have access to your profile, inbox, questions, answers and favorites for each of
   your registered site.
3. View syntax colored code.
4. Notification on replies to your question, answer or comment.
5. Search and advanced search.
6. Learn a topic by creating and saving your advanced search and choosing to add it as tab in the front page.

**Platform**
Android 4.0+ (API Level >= 14)

**License**
Free in Google Play. [Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prasanna.android.stacknetwork).

**Feedback**
It will be really helpful to receive any kind of feedback. This is my first mobile application and I have zero prior experience with user experience or user interface design. So any critique or feedback will be nice.

**Screenshots**
[image: Login] [image: Sites] [image: Questions] [image: Tags] [image: Question] [image: Post Comment] [image: Pretty Code] [image: Comments] [image: User Profile] [image: User Profile Answer] [image: Saved searches] [image: Advanced Search Results]

Comment: Fixed a crash in settings and have submitted the apk for upgrade. Hopefully this resolves the issue.

Comment: I have an Android phone with 4.0.4 (ICS) - I'll give this a try later.

Comment: Hello Prasanna, are you there ?

Comment: @Raynold Yes, I am here.

Comment: @Prasanna, can you help me in my question , http://stackapps.com/q/4039/20460

Comment: How do you do this part "Login and have access to your profile, inbox, questions, answers and favorites for each of your registered site. " , which is point 2, in your question ?

Comment: Can you upload apk or list this app on the Amazon Appstore for people without play store access?

Comment: @Cagentdog I have submitted the app to Amazon Appstore. Hopefully it is available for download shortly.

Comment: Please see my [question](http://stackapps.com/questions/4437/stackx-app-problem-signing-in-with-google-id) on this site.

Comment: @PM77-1 I also noticed issues with logging in. The issue seems to be with client OAuth flow of Stack Exchange API. After you put in your login credentials are you seeing an empty white page with title as "Login"? Yes, the app does support posting of comments. For future reference, you can email me with issues, the email is available in the app listing in Play Store.

Comment: No I do not see a blank page. I added actual screen shots to my question.