# Looking for Android app that allows posting questions/comments to SE sites

Tags: discussion, app-request, android, posts

I remember that not so long ago all the apps had a limited, read-only functionality. I wonder if it has changed?

Is there an Android app that allows you to post questions/comments to SE sites?

Answer (score 2):

[The stack exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) *officially* does not support posting questions or answers, but it does allow posting comments.

So you can install [the StackX app](https://stackapps.com/q/3901/7653) and use it to comment on posts.

There is also [an **Official Android App** in alpha development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/190200/148310).  It looks like they are still taking sign-ups for <strike>guinea pigs</strike> volunteers. ;)