# StackX app - problem signing in with Google ID

Tags: support, authentication, android

I have a problem with [StackX](https://stackapps.com/questions/3901/stackx-android-application-for-stack-exchange-free-ui-and-optimization-upgr) app on my Samsung Galaxy 4 phone (Android 4.3).  I'm logging to StackExchange in general, and StackOferflow in particular, using my Google ID. The app does not recognize my id as **valid existing** ID.

[image]_________________[image]

I did not find any other way to contact the developer besides StackApps and I do not believe that rating page is an appropriate venue for tech support.

1. Does anybody else have such problem?
2. This app claims to be able to **post comments** (not just to view stuff). Are there other Android apps with such capabilities?

Comment: This looks like a bug with Stack Exchange API. I have created a support request here: http://stackapps.com/questions/4438/implicit-oauth-flow-stopped-working-redirect-happening-to-a-non-existent-url

Comment: @Prasanna  How soon something like this could be addressed?

Comment: I don't know. Considering this is the weekend, I don't expect Stack Exchange guys to respond before Monday. Hopefully someone from the Stack Exchange team can respond to it soon.

Comment: There is a workaround for this. Once you have entered the credentials and staring at a blank page, go back to Settings and click Login again, this time you will be successfully logged in,

Comment: @Prasanna : I do **not** get a blank page. I get "*This login is new to Stack Exchange*" screen.  I have posted the screen where I select to use Google id and the screen that comes after.

Comment: Looks like your Google account is not linked with Stack exchange.

Comment: This is how I **always** login to Stack Overflow and other sites.  This is how I'm logged in now.

Comment: Not sure what  changed,  but I was able to login yesterday with exactly the same credentials.

Comment: I updated the app with a workaround. Regarding the bug filed, no one from Stack Exchange have gotten back yet. Poor support.