# Implicit OAuth Flow stopped working. Redirect happening to a non existent URL

Tags: bug, api-v2, oauth2

The following URL is first hit when a user clicks on Login:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=202&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fstackexchange.com%2foauth%2flogin_success&scope=read_inbox,no_expiry,write_access
```

which redirects to

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=202&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fstackexchange.com%2foauth%2flogin_success&scope=read_inbox,no_expiry,write_access&response_type=token&state=&returnurl=%2foauth%2fdialog%3fclient_id%3d202%26redirect_uri%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fstackexchange.com%252foauth%252flogin_success%26scope%3dread_inbox%2cno_expiry%2cwrite_access%26response_type%3dtoken%26state%3d
```

which shows the list of OpenID providers to login.

You pick a OpenID provider(Yahoo in my case, bug was reported when using Google as well) and login, after which the redirection happens to

```
https://stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/?s=....
```

And then the final step where the error happens, after the above URL, another redirection happens to the following URL

```
https://stackexchange.com/%2foauth%2fdialog%3fclient_id%3d202%26redirect_uri%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fstackexchange.com%252foauth%252flogin_success%26scope%3dread_inbox%2cno_expiry%2cwrite_access%26response_type%3dtoken%26state%3d
```

The above URL fails to load or redirect to Approve/Reject page. All I see is an empty page.

The workaround in the app is to for the user to go click Login again after looking into the blank page at which point the first request gets sent again and Approve/reject page is displayed.

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=202&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fstackexchange.com%2foauth%2flogin_success&scope=read_inbox,no_expiry,write_access
```

I have not made any changes to authentication code in my app. This error started happening about a week ago. I am able to reproduce this using a browser to login in my phone.

Comment: Should be fixed now. See http://stackapps.com/questions/6938/implicit-flow-isnt-redirecting